# Sync with a Directory Listing of Web Server

Tags: synchronization, http

Is there an easy way to keep a folder synced with a directory listing via HTTP?

**Edit**:

Thanks for the tip with wget! I created a shell script and added it as a cron job:

```
remote_dirs=( "http://example.com/" "…") # Add your remote HTTP directories here
local_dirs=(  "~/examplecom" "…")

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#local_dirs[@]} ; i++ )) do
cd "${local_dirs[$i]}"
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A "*.pdf" -nd -nc ${remote_dirs[$i]}
done

# Explanation:
# -r            to download recursively
# -l1           to include only one directory depth
# --no-parent   to exclude parent directories
# -A "*.pdf"    to accept only .pdf files
# -nd           to prevent wget to create directories for everything
# -N            to make wget to download only new files
```

**Edit 2:**
As mentioned below one could also use `--mirror` (`-m`), which is the shorthand for `-r -N`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you accept the answer that you feel best helped you resolve your question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`wget` is a great tool.

Use `wget -m http://somesite.com/directory`

```
-m
--mirror
    Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on
    recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and
    keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to 
    -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.
```

Answer (score 9):

Like rsync, but use [zsync](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/) to get from an httpd server.

Comment: There is not much documentation for zsync on the Internet. It would be really nice if you could elaborate on your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Behrooz - I actually use `lftp` and its `mirror` command now instead.